# How do I slow down music in Rosegarden without editing the tempo permanently?

Tags: midi, rosegarden

I want to hear what's going on in the music, but it's a bit too fast. I want to temporarily slow down it.

I can edit the tempo, listen/edit, then edit the tempo back; but it's too invasive.

Comment: I never got to mess with rose garden much. But you should find out how to `1)` select a section of the audio track you want to reduce the tempo. `2)` fine the option to reduce the tempo…

Comment: So basically look on how to do 1 & 2 one at a time and then once you found it, combine them.

Comment: What does mean "section of the audio track"? There are MIDI tracks and segments inside it. I can only select a segment.

Comment: The tempo can also be ramped, so tricky to edit.

Comment: In audacity, you can select a section of the audio track to edit. So can you do the same in RG?

Comment: It is about Audacity. Audacity is audio editor, Rosegarden is MIDI editor. There are mostly notes, pitch, instruments, tempo etc. there, not samples and effects.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok. I see, id have to install ire in a vm and see if i can figure it out. You should post a screenshot of what you want to do